# Custom date format parsing in python

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am trying to the parse dates of the format **'2016-04-15T12:24:20.707Z'** in Python, tried **strptime**, doesn't work and I also tried django **parse_datetime** but it only returns none as the value

Comment: Can you show how you called the `striptime`, etc.?

Comment: Specify `doesn't work`

Comment: Btw looks like your format is pretty standard. It mislead search.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may try this way :

```
from datetime import datetime
date_str = '2016-04-15T12:24:20.707Z'
date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")

print(date)
```

**Output:**

```
2016-04-15 12:24:20.707000
```

Comment: ValueError: time data "('2016-04-15T12:24:20.707Z',)" does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ' is the error I am getting when I try the same thing, maybe because I am retrieving it from the database and not hardcoding it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the format as **`"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"`** while conversion

```
In [11]: from datetime import datetime

In [12]: out_format = "%Y-%m-%d"

In [13]: input_format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"

In [14]: date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(time,input_format)

In [15]: date_time_obj
Out[15]: datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 15, 12, 24, 20, 707000)

In [16]: date_time_str = date_time_obj.strftime(out_format)

In [17]: date_time_str
Out[17]: '2016-04-15'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import dateutil.parser
from datetime import datetime 

dt = dateutil.parser.parse('2016-04-15T12:24:20.707Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working alright:

```
import dateparser
dateparser.parse('2016-04-15T12:24:20.707Z')

> datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 15, 12, 24, 20, 707000, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'Z'>)
```

Comment: It works fine, when I hardcode the date as the parameter to parse, since I am retrieving the date from mysql raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr)
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', "('2016-04-15T12:24:20.707Z',)")

Comment: Well, it looks like the datestring from your DB is a tuple ... you might need to remove the double quotes and brackets. Alternatively you could try to eval the string and access the first element in the tuple which should be the datestring. Btw: this is exactly why questions should contain a minimal-complete example since this whole thread is now a instance of an XY-Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [iso8601](https://pypi.org/project/iso8601/) package is what you need

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way if you need something on the fly:

This returns the current datetime in UTC, as a datetime object then immediately converts it to your preferred custom format.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from time import strftime

# Get UTC Time datetime object and convert it to your preferred format.
print(f"Regular    : { datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }")  # Regular    : 2022-06-04 23:08:27
print(f"Log  Format: { datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') }")      # Log  Format: 20220604_230827
print(f"YMD  Format: { datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }")           # YMD  Format: 2022-06-04
print(f"Time Format: { datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%H:%M:%S') }")           # Time Format: 23:08:27

# Without the f'String'
print(datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))  # Regular    : 2022-06-04 23:08:27
print(datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'))      # Log  Format: 20220604_230827
print(datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))           # YMD  Format: 2022-06-04
print(datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%H%M%S'))             # Time Format: 23:08:27


# Details:
# Get current DateTime in UTC
datetime.now(timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 4, 23, 13, 27, 498392, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
type(datetime.now(timezone.utc))
# <class 'datetime.datetime'>

# Use the strftime on the datetime object directly
datetime(2022, 6, 4, 23, 13, 27, 498392, tzinfo=timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# '2022-06-04 23:13:27'
type(datetime(2022, 6, 4, 23, 13, 27, 498392, tzinfo=timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
# <class 'str'>
```